# Accessing subclass variables in a superclass in Ruby

Tags: ruby, class, oop

So, I've been studying Ruby for over two weeks now and I'm having some issues understanding the whole OOP thing.

[In this lesson](https://launchschool.com/books/oo_ruby/read/inheritance#methodlookup), in the exercises in the end, we are asked to create a superclass of `vehicle` and add non-specific behavior to it, and then create a `MyCar` and a `MyTruck` subclasses that inherit from it and also have a constant that separates them. So I did like so:

```
class Vehicle

  attr_accessor :color, :curr_speed
  attr_reader :year, :model

  def initialize(y, c, m)
    @year = y
    @color = c
    @model = m
  end

  #SOME OTHER METHODS

  def to_s
    "My #{VEHICLE_TYPE} is a #{self.model} #{self.year} of color #{self.color}."
  end      
end

class MyCar < Vehicle
  VEHICLE_TYPE = 'car'
end

class MyTruck < Vehicle
  VEHICLE_TYPE = 'truck'
end
```

I also redefined the `to_s` method so that it would return a string that would say what kind of vehicle it is along with the other info. Now, the exercise does not ask us to do that -- in fact, they define a to_s method for `MyCar` and another to `MyTruck` that starts with "My car..." or "My truck..." but I feel like this goes against the DRY principle.

Thing is, it seems that Ruby does not accept a subclass variable passed in a superclass method. If I use `#{VEHICLE_TYPE}` it throws a `uninitialized constant Vehicle::VEHICLE_TYPE (NameError)`, and if I use `#{self.VEHICLE_TYPE}` it throws a `undefined method 'VEHICLE_TYPE' for Vehicle:Class (NoMethodError)`.

Am I correct in my assumption that Ruby does not accept a subclass variable in a superclass? And how could I go about to fix this issue in a similar fashion? Because I thought about simply adding another parameter to `initizalize` for type, store in a superclass instance variable and be done with it, but I don't think it would serve the purpose of the exercise.

And bear in mind that I'm a newbie!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right.  The superclass can't use the shortcut notation of `VEHICLE_TYPE` to access the constant you've defined.

When you want to access a constant outside of the class it is defined in, you can access it using a qualified name like:

```rb
Car::VEHICLE_TYPE
```

You were getting pretty close on your `self.VEHICLE_TYPE` attempt.  But to provide a generic replacement for something like `Car::`, you'd need to use `self.class::`.

So your `to_s` method would look like:

```rb
def to_s
  "My #{self.class::VEHICLE_TYPE} is a #{self.model} #{self.year} of color #{self.color}."
end
```

This will work as long as each instantiable class defines that constant.

Comment: It worked, but the concept of qualified name is still foreign to me. So in, `Car::VEHICLE_TYPE`, we're specifically telling ruby to check the `VEHICLE_TYPE` constant inside the `Car` class? Would that be accessible anywhere in the program?

Comment: A [fully qualified name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_name) is an unambiguous name used to specify an object.  Yes, constants are special and are available anywhere in the program.  [This description](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/the-ruby-programming/9780596516178/ch04s03.html) from O'Reilly is pretty good.